# Use array_position() function to get the most frequent value for column from pg_stats

Tags: postgresql, performance, datatypes, array, postgresql-performance

I'm trying to execute this simple query in order to check whether some value (*1000*) belongs to MCV list used by Postgres query optimizer:

```
SELECT array_position(most_common_vals, 1000) 
FROM pg_stats 
WHERE tablename = 'tenk1' 
AND attname = 'unique1';
```

But receive the following error message:

> ```
> ERROR:  function array_position(anyarray, integer) does not exist
> ```

How can it be fixed?

`array_position()` is the standard function as described [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/arrays.html#ARRAYS-SEARCHING) and the following statement returns *2* as expected:

```
SELECT array_position('{1,2,3}', 2);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Solution

Assuming the data type of your column `tenk1.unique1` is `integer`:

```
SELECT array_position(most_common_vals::text::int[], 1000) 
FROM   pg_stats 
WHERE  tablename = 'tenk1' 
AND    attname = 'unique1';
```

Use your actual column type and the corresponding array type.
You get the position, or NULL if the value is not in the MCV list.

The solution is short - unlike the ...

#### Explanation

The function [`array_position()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) is defined to take `(anyarray, anyelement)` (or `(anyarray, anyelement, integer)` for the second variant).

The column [`pg_stats.most_common_vals`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/view-pg-stats.html) has the polymorphic data type **`anyarray`** to be able to hold arrays of any data type - for obvious reasons.

`anyarray` and `anyelement` are not allowed as data types for user-created tables. For users, both are [polymorphic **pseudo-types**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/extend-type-system.html#EXTEND-TYPES-POLYMORPHIC). (But Postgres can use them in system tables.)

Multiple polymorphic variables in the same function have to resolve to the same (or corresponding) data types. The manual:

> Furthermore, if there are positions declared `anyarray` and others
>   declared `anyelement`, the actual array type in the `anyarray` positions
>   must be an array whose elements are the same type appearing in the
>   anyelement positions.

And:

> Thus, when more than one argument position is declared with a
>   polymorphic type, the net effect is that **only certain combinations of
>   actual argument types are allowed**.

Bold emphasis mine.

You have found a corner case where [function type resolution](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/typeconv-func.html) fails for the combination of the polymorphic `anyarray` with an `integer` - or *any* non-polymorphic type in second position.

`1000` in your expression `array_position(most_common_vals, 1000)` is a numeric constant resolving to `integer`. These would fail in similar fashion:

```
array_position(most_common_vals, '1000')  -- untyped string literal
```

> ```
> ERROR:  function array_position(anyarray, unknown) does not exist
> ```

```
array_position(most_common_vals, '1000'::text)
```

> ```
> ERROR:  function array_position(anyarray, text) does not exist
> ```

Furthermore, there are no casts defined for `anyarray`, being a pseudo-type in user-land:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_cast WHERE castsource = 'anyarray'::regtype;  -- nothing found
```

The workaround is to cast to `text` as stepping stone, since any type can be cast to `text`. Then cast to `integer[]`, arriving at the solution above.

In closing, *I think* this is a shortcoming in function type resolution that could be resolved (easily?). But since the data type `anyarray` is not supposed to be used like this in user-land to begin with I doubt that any developer will spend time on it ...